# how to take out a variable from one function to another

Tags: javascript

I have two different functions. How can I take the value of the variable from the first function to use in the second function? My Javascript code:

```
function test(){

    var a = 5;
    var b = 9;
    var c = a + b;
}

function testB(){

    var R = c + 15;
    console.log(R)
}
```

My HTML code: (Just un button)

```
<button onclick="testB()"> Test Function</button>
```

Comment: How/when/where is `test` called? The usual way to get a value "out" is to `return` it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 3):

Return the value from the `test()` function, and call it in the `testB` function:

```js
function test(){
  var a = 5;
  var b = 9;
  var c = a + b;
  return c;
}

function testB(){
  var c = test();
  var R = c + 15;
  console.log(R)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testB()"> Test Function</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function test(){

    var a = 5;
    var b = 9;
    return a + b;
}

function testB(){

    var R = test() + 15;
    console.log(R)
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testB()">Click</button>
```

If you want to use the value of output of a funtion, you need to return the value. Here test() function returns the value of a+b and it is being used in testB() function.

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches to this problem.

One solution is to make your variable c global. That means declaring it outside of your functions, like this:

```
var c;
function test(){
    var a = 5;
    var b = 9;
    c = a + b;
}
```

Than you can use variable c in your second function. Also you are not calling your test function anywhere in the code.

```
function testB(){
    var R = c + 15;
    console.log(R)
}
```

Other solution is to return a value from your first function:

```
function test(){
    var a = 5;
    var b = 9;
    return a + b;
}
```

Than you can call test function inside of your testB function

```
function testB(){
    var R = test() + 15;
    console.log(R)
}
```